# For each loop is not executing when uploaded at 000webhost server

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have an application that post data to a php file in an online server. When the post is done i get a garbage of html code. In it says I have a php error and that is Invalid argument supplied for each() on line 33. However this problem does not occur if I run it  in localhost. I don't understand why this problem is occuring. So someone please help me to solve it.

The following is my jsonparser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getandpostJSONFromUrl(String url, String method,JSONArray name) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            if (method == "POST") {


                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                //params.setParameter("data", auth);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


                List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", name.toString()));

                for (NameValuePair nvp : postParams) {
                    String name2 = nvp.getName();
                    String value = nvp.getValue();
                    Log.d("NameValue pair content", ""+name2+""+value);
                }


                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams,HTTP.UTF_8);


                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
                Log.d("",responseBody);
            }
            if (method == "GET") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (method == "POST") {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer error", "Buffer error" + e);
            }

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

The following is the php file on the server

```
<?php
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        /*define('DB_NAME', 'a1422982_sshop');
                        define('DB_USER', 'root');
                        define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
                        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');*/

        define('DB_NAME', 'onlineshop');
        define('DB_USER', 'shop');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
        define('DB_HOST', 'mysql28.000webhost.com'); 


                        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

                        if(!$link){
                        die('could not connect: '.msql_error());
                        }

                        $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

                        if(!$db_selected){
                        die('Can not  use '.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
                        }

                        //var_dump(json_decode ($_POST['json'])));

                        if($_POST['json']){
                            $parsed = json_decode($_POST['json'],TRUE);

                            $i=0;

                            foreach ($parsed as $obj) {
                                 $ProductName = $obj['Name'];   
                                 $ProductQuantity= $obj['Quantity'];
                                 $sql="Update productlist Set Quantity='$ProductQuantity' where Name='$ProductName';";

                                 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
                                  if(! $retval )
                                    {
                                      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
                                    }
                                 $i++;

                                 echo   $ProductName." ".$ProductQuantity;
                             }
                        }else{
                            echo "empty";
                        }


?>
```

Comment: You should add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your PHP file and probably you will see some errors

Comment: And not leave to use searching for line 33 but tell which line that is.

Comment: `if($_POST['json']){` better change to `if (isset($_POST['json'])){`.

Comment: on line 33-> foreach ($parsed as $obj) { @ greenapps

Comment: Then $parsed is invalid. Find out why. Print out or let the script return the json text to see if it is different from the one you posted. And use isset()! Tell if you applied all suggested changes.

Comment: I used this print_r( $parsed); after $parsed = json_decode($_POST['json'],TRUE); but nothing is printed in my log cat @ greenapps and also is i have used the isset() as you have shown

Answer (score 0):

there's a missing options on your HttpPost request set the entity metadata and the resulting entity as string.

In your java code you can do this:

```
   Map<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
   postData.put("KEY", "yourvalue");
   JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(postData);

   StringEntity jsonStringEntity = new StringEntity(holder.toString());

   httpost.setEntity(jsonStringEntity);
   httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

in that way your PHP code could actually parse your post data since json_decode() expecting json as parameter.